# Decimal format in textfield in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I have text field with placeholder 00.00 . I want to enter number in that format. 
Please help

Comment: You want to enter or you want user to enter and validate in given format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate Numeric Input to UITextField as the User Enters Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344159/validate-numeric-input-to-uitextfield-as-the-user-enters-input)

Answer (score 0):

Make keyboard type numeric. And internally use below code to get double value

```
      NSString *value =textfield_name.text;
      double doubleValue = [value doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Make your class the delegate for `yourTextField`, and add the codes as used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344159/validate-numeric-input-to-uitextfield-as-the-user-enters-input).

```
NSString *enteredValue=@"99.129";//get your value from textfield as yourField.text
double doubleValue=[enteredValue doubleValue];
NSString *formattedDoubleValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",doubleValue];
NSLog(@"->%@",formattedDoubleValue);//now you can set back to the textfield as yourField.text=formattedDoubleValue
```

Alternatively, you can use NSNumberFormatter for this.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter=[NSNumberFormatter new];
[numFormatter setFormat:@"00.00"];
NSString *str=[numFormatter stringFromNumber:@99.129];
NSLog(@"->%@",str);
```

---

**EDIT:** As per your comment

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (textField == self.yourTextField){
        NSLog(@"here");
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]{1,2})(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:nil];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
        if (numberOfMatches==0){
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: when entering in text field itself it should validate.can help please