# how to validate UITextfield such that it should contain only numbers,no os characters less than 2

Tags: ios

I want to validate my UITextfield for number of characters less than 2 and only numbers should be entered... 
[seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344159/validate-numeric-input-to-uitextfield-as-the-user-enters-input)

Comment: What do you mean with only characters less than 2?

Comment: try the answer posted...

Answer (score 6):

Try this one...

```
#define NUMBERS_ONLY @"1234567890"
#define CHARACTER_LIMIT 2
```

and in this method----

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:NUMBERS_ONLY] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= CHARACTER_LIMIT));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works!!

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) return YES;
unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:0];
    if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c])
    {
        int maxVal = 2;
        if (textField.text.length >= maxVal)
            return NO;
        else
            return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of dealing with this in iOS is attaching a `UITextFieldDelegate` to your `UITextField`, and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method. Inside this method you can validate the string

use property `length` to achieve this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if([textField.text length]<2)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: Actually the standard in iOS and MacOS X is to use key-value coding validation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html). An example of this is: https://github.com/quellish/KVCValidationExample

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if([textField.text length]<2)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

and assign `NSNumberkeyboard` type to the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to declare a `NSCharaterSet` with all letters and check that the field's text does not contain any of them:

```
NSCharacterSet *alphabet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
if ([[self.label.text lowercaseString] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:alphabet].location != NSNotFound) 
{
     NSLog(@"Found letters!");
}
```