# How to prevent record a negative or zero number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem for my xCode application.

My application is about record outcome. Thus the items values should be positive. I try to prevent record negative or zero value while choosing an item, but my code did not function.

This is my code to record an item

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Outcome Item Value" message:@"Please enter an outcome item value" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[alert show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex == 0) {

  }
  else
  {
    OutcomeItem* newOutcomeItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OutcomeItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    newOutcomeItem.outcomeName = self.selectedOutcomeItem.outcomeName;
    newOutcomeItem.outcomeValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text doubleValue]];


    if (newOutcomeItem.outcomeValue <= 0) {

        NSLog(@"Invalid Value");
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {

        [self.delegate addOutcomeItem:newOutcomeItem];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
  }
}
```

my OutcomeItem.h is

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import<CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class OutcomeRecord;
@interface OutcomeItem : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *outcomeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain） NSNumber *outcomeValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) OutcomeRecord *outcomeRecord;
@end;
```

OutcomeItem.m is

```
#import "OutcomeItem.h"
#import "OutcomeRecord.h"

@implementation OutcomeItem
@dynamic outcomeName;
@dynamic outcomeValue;
@dynamic outcomeRecord;
@end
```

Add outcome item method is

```
-(void)addOutcomeItem:(OutcomeItem *)outcomeItem
```

{
    [self.currentOutcomeRecord addOutcomeItemsObject:outcomeItem];
    self.outcomeRecordItemList = [self.currentOutcomeRecord.outcomeItems allObjects];

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSError* error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not save outcome item insertion:\n%@", error.userInfo);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that the value from the text is taken ad a number? try to log after the assignment

Comment: please add the implementation of OutcomeItem class.

Comment: also the implementation of addOutcomeItem function

Comment: yup, the value could be taken as a number. But it could be negative, zero and positive. If I input a letter or symbol, my application will treat it as a 0 valued item

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. You need cast to a doubleValue from NSNumber.

```
 NSNumber *outcomeValueX = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text doubleValue]];

 if (outcomeValueX.doubleValue <= 0) {  
        NSLog(@"Invalid Value");
 }
```

Ideally I would try to validate it with a UITextFieldDelegate to your UITextField, and implement textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString.

See here: [How to Test Character Input to UITextField as the User Enters Characters and Prevent Invalid Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344159/validate-numeric-input-to-uitextfield-as-the-user-enters-input)

I would also not add a new outcomeItem until the value is validated.

Comment: so, `NSString` -> `double` -> `NSNumber` -> `double`? Why `NSNumber`?

Comment: Exactly! Funny to miss that! ;) Something like the following would be enough: double myCoolDouble = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text doubleValue]