# Validation using Regular Expressions in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, validation, xcode6, nsregularexpression

I'm implementing validation for username field using Regular Expression(Regex) in iOS. I don't want username to start with the word "guest". I tried below code but it's not working.

```
[txtUserName addRegx:@"^(guest)" withMsg:@"Username Can't start with the word guest"];
```

Ideas?

Comment: Did you [check this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9352938/3832970)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use this Regex:

```
^(?!guest).*$
```

Explanation:

**^** assert position at start of the string

**(?!guest)** Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
guest matches the characters guest literally (case sensitive)

**.*** matches any character (except newline)

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

**$** assert position at end of the string

**EDIT:**

To make it case insensitive you can try this:

```
^(?i:(?!guest)).*$
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I don't want this to be case sensitive. It should also work for GUEST or gUEst. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't want this to be case sensitive. It should also work for GUEST or gUEst.

Comment: @MugheesMusaddiq:- Then try this: `^(?i:(?!guest)).*$` Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the ( ) like the following:

```
[txtUserName addRegx:@"^guest" withMsg:@"Username Can't start with the word guest"];
```

Comment: Thanks but it accepts guest as a first word of user name and I want exactly opposite of it. I don't want username textField to accept "guest" as a first word. Any suggestions?